# Average of cells with time HH:MM:SS

Tags: libreoffice

I am trying to get the average of a column for which the data type is Time (format HH:MM:SS)
The function AVERAGE doesn't seem to work for this data type.

Comment: Convert values to seconds, compute the average, convert back to time.  Not something I'd _like_ to do with Excel functions, but it's entirely possible to do it.

Comment: Is that a cell actually formatted as time, or a string that looks like time? My LibreOffice seems to handle times as floating point values of days, and `average()` works ok for them.
(This would probably be more fit to [superuser](https://superuser.com/), though)

Comment: Some input and the corresponding output you should be providing.

Comment: Those are cells formatted as a time with the following format : HH:MM:SS

Comment: Actually, I now realize that my input time looks like this and has an ' at the beginning : '01:07:36